# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2012, not using Java/c# or any other lang

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

I am facing this problem, can anyone please help me.

```
Error messages: 
===================================

Cannot connect to WAHEGURU\SQLEXPRESS.

===================================

Instance failure. (System.Data)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
```

Comment: You are giving too little information. Is this a local or network server? Were you able to connect before? Are you the server administrator?

Comment: it is a local server.
yes i was able to connect before.
i am the administrator.

Comment: And what happened in between? Is the service running? Do you have a firewall? Is the server an Express Edition? Did you try with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, and with/without the instance name?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing SSMS with correct configuration and libraries and use correct path of sql server. It will work if you use the path in correct format and correct server instance name like 
[Server-Name][SQL-INSTANCE-NAME-ON-THE-SERVER]

For some reference please go through these link, hope it might help:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic940068-391-1.aspx
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1377174.aspx?Failed+to+generate+a+user+instance+of+SQL+Server](http://forums.asp.net/t/1377174.aspx?Failed%20to%20generate%20a%20user%20instance%20of%20SQL%20Server)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/219f42cf-5c99-4a72-9acb-249210c835e2/failed-to-generate-a-user-instance-of-sql-server-due-to-a-failure-in-starting-the-process-for-the?forum=lightswitchgeneral